# VB.net Click on a certain coordinate

Tags: vb.net, coordinate

i'm making a windows application that would open a program and click on certain coordinates, first i need to know how to get a coordinate, which i already know, but how do I let my mouse click on a certain position? Simply it would be somthing like mouse.Click(coordinate). I don't know, could anyone help?

Regards

Comment: I get this error:

A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsProject!WindowsProject.Form1::mouse_event' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Answer (score 1):

I tried putting this as a comment, but SO wouldn't put the comment up after I typed it, so I had to put what I had as an answer.

Here are two links that might have what you're looking to do: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b68f005-1d09-4085-b236-b05797df3bf0/how-to-make-the-mouse-click

and

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2518c35-ed77-42b3-a9c4-705238d714c2/mouse-click

And if you just want to click a button, you could use

```
button.Performclick()
```

But I don't think that there's any simple way (such as Mouse.Click()) to make the mouse click anywhere.

HTH